# Im new to mapbox and I want to restrict the viewing of my map to my campus only, how do I do it?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

im using android studio and mapbox and i saw other post like using bounding box and setScrollableAreaLimit() but i dont know how to use them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: any fix here ? @Mr. Dontknowhowtocode ?

Comment: right now im not using mapbox instead i used google maps and i somehow did it the instructions btw can be found in the net